# Created a wireless network from my Ubuntu, it can't be seen by nearby devices

Tags: wireless, networking

I created a wireless network from my Ubuntu, I wanted to connect to that network from my tablet (I don't want to share internet or anything, I just want both devices on the same network).

But the tablet (android) could not detect the network I just created, when I try to define it in the tablet it says "Not in range"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the wireless network you created is set to **ad-hoc** network by default, which is not detected by mobile device, unless you do some kernel mods in your mobile device.
One way to get out of this problem is to use packages like

> ap-hotspot

For more info and how to install ap-hotspot [click here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.webupd8.org%2F2013%2F06%2Fhow-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access.html&ei=IXk-U6bKMoaYrAfMvYDgCA&usg=AFQjCNE8iStT7LJL1yyIDwM6hWCFF2hfeA&sig2=A4j86stiAWz2akKaS0Ursg&bvm=bv.64125504,d.bmk)

Comment: Unfortunately my wireless card doesn't support Access Point Mode, so I can't run it :(